# Update value based on subquery returning more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this probably simple SQL question.

```
UPDATE parts
SET partscnt=partscnt-1
WHERE idparts = (SELECT idparts FROM ordercontent WHERE idOrder=4);
```

Problem is that the subquery returns 5 values, and i want the update done on each of the values.

Update:
The ordercontent table has an ID for the order and a row idparts. If several of the same parts are hooked to the same order the table looks like this:

```
ID idparts
4  147
4  147
4  147
4  55
4  33
```

So I need to decrement the partscount three times for the part with id 147.

How can I change this query to achieve that?

Comment: Use `IN` and not `=` in your WHERE clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the quantity of every `idparts` in `ordercontent` for the specified order:

```
SELECT idparts,
       COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM ordercontent
WHERE idOrder = 4
GROUP BY idparts
```

Join the result of the above to `parts` and use the `cnt` values to update `partscnt`:

```
UPDATE parts p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT idparts,
           COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM ordercontent
    WHERE idOrder = 4
    GROUP BY idparts
) o
ON p.idparts = o.idparts
SET p.partscnt = p.partscnt - o.cnt
;
```

Comment: I had to throw in group by idparts in the count query, but this worked great ! Thank you thank you !

Comment: Ah, yes, I meant to put GROUP BY there but, silly me, just failed to do that. Thanks, I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try:

```
UPDATE parts 
SET partscnt = partscnt-1 
WHERE idparts IN (
    SELECT idparts 
    FROM ordercontent 
    WHERE idOrder = 4
);
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. But i have some where there are several identical values returned from the subquery, but still want the partscnt to be decremented. Is there a way for that?

Comment: @kincaid: Would be great if you updated your question to clarify that.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I guess they mean the column needs to be decremented by however many times the correspondent `idparts` is encountered in `ordercontent` (for the specified `idOrder`).

Comment: I have updated the question. Andriy M : yes that is what i need to do.

Comment: Would this work? `UPDATE parts SET partscnt=partscnt-(SELECT count(idparts) FROM ordercontent WHERE idOrder=4) WHERE idparts IN (SELECT idparts FROM ordercontent WHERE idOrder=4);` Untested

Answer (score 0):

Replace '=' with IN:

> UPDATE parts SET partscnt=partscnt-1 WHERE idparts **IN** (SELECT
>   idparts FROM ordercontent WHERE idOrder=4);

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE parts 
SET partscnt=partscnt-1 
WHERE idparts IN
    (SELECT idparts FROM ordercontent WHERE idOrder=4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE parts p1
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT *  
   FROM ordercontent WHERE idOrder = 4
) p2 ON p1.idparts = p2.idparts
SET p1.partscnt = p2.partscnt-1
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace "-1" with "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ordercontent WHERE isOrder = 4)"